# Blender not UV unwrapping object?

Tags: modeling

Trying to UV unwrap an object. I have marked the seams, applied the scale, and selected all the faces necessary, but it doesnt unwrap :/

How do I fix this?

Here's the blend:

[image]

Comment: In my little test it seems to work fine. Remember that if you would like to see the uvmap upon the Render Result, you should save it as image and re-open it in the image editor.

Comment: When I do "U" > "unwrap", nothing shows up in the UV editor :/

Comment: Did you unlink the Render Result image (by clicking the cross) or tried to use an image texture?

Comment: In the UV/Image editor select Image->New Image and then unwrap.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f6039929cc768e7f73e4e32277f99969.png This is what I get when I open a new image. If i deslect it, everything just goes black :/

Comment: That *is* the UvMap. The black/intense orange colour comes from the overlapping islands: you probably have a few tiny faces that are in need of more care, maybe the seams should be adjusted, and so on...the tool is working in my opinion, you just have to refine your unwrap to get better results.

Comment: Geez louis, what is this satan spawn...

https://i.gyazo.com/270136f22883fff37c0d345721298a45.png

Is there any place where i can learn to improve this/improve this through some tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the seams that you have marked are not enough

the only way that you can fix this is to refine your seam
for example
i selected a separated part of your staff and uv unwrapped it

[image]
as you can see its not good
to fix this part you can either add an other seam
[image]

or for this specific part of the staff you can delete the inner faces that are not visible from any angle 
[image]

the second way is pretty much like adding a seam except this way you get rid of some faces that are useless (not visible at all), reducing the file size (just a bit, but can make big different if you do it for every part) and also its easier to manage and paint less faces

by the way i used <kbd>L</kbd> to select separated part and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert selecting and <kbd>H</kbd> to hide other faces. <kbd>ALT</kbd> +<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything

i can refine more parts if you have problems

hope it help

Comment: Perfect! I understand :)